# Vector spaces - finding bases in $\mathbb Z_7^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the vector space $\mathbb Z_7^2$ = {$(a,b) : a,b$ $\in$ $\mathbb Z_7$}.

a) Let $S$ = {$(1,3),(5,1)$}. Prove that $S$ is a linearly dependent subset of $\mathbb Z_7^2$.

b) Explaining your reasoning, find a basis for $\mathbb Z_7^2$ containing $(2,4)$.

c) How many different bases are there for $\mathbb Z_7^2$? Justify your answer.

Part a):

Let $S$ be a set of non-zero vectors. Then $S$ is linearly dependent if for some positive integer $n$, there exist distinct vectors $\mathbf v_1$, $\mathbf v_2$, ... , $\mathbf v_n$ $\in$ $S$ and scalars $a_1$, $a_2$, ... , $a_n$, not all zero, such that:

$a_1$$\mathbf v_1$ + $a_2$$\mathbf v_2$ + ... + $a_n$$\mathbf v_n$ =$\mathbf 0$.

Let $\mathbf v_1$ = $(1,3)$, $\mathbf v_2$ = $(5,1)$, $a_1$ = $2$ and $a_2$ = $1$. Then $2$$(1,3)$ + $1$$(5,1)$ = $(0,0)$ = $\mathbf 0$.

b) Using the standard basis {$(1,0),(0,1)$} for $\mathbb Z_7^2$, clearly {$(2,4),(1,0),(0,1)$} spans $\mathbb Z_7^2$ because it contains a basis.

Note that $(2,4)$ = $2(1,0)$ + $4(0,1)$. Is it correct to deduce that $(1,0)$ = $4(2,4)$ - $2(0,1)$ and then say hence the span of {$(2,4),(0,1)$} equals the span of {$(2,4),(1,0),(0,1)$}? I can then argue I have a set $B$ = {$(2,4),(0,1)$} which contains {$(2,4)$} and spans $\mathbb Z_7^2$. Following on from that, if $a(2,4)$ + $b(0,1)$ = $(0,0)$, then $2a$ + $0$ = $0$ and $4a$ + $b$ = $0$ which implies $a=b=0$. Therefore, $B$ is linearly independent. This is a linearly independent spanning set i.e. a basis for $\mathbb Z_7^2$ containing the set {$(2,4)$}.

c) I'm not sure where to start with this part. I presume it follows on from b) but I'm not sure what the best approach is.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for c)** (might also be used for b)

To have a basis for $\mathbf F_7^2$, you first choose a non-zero vector, which are 7^2-1 in number. Then you choose a vector which is not a multiple of the previous one. How many of these are there?

**Note:**

The same argument  may be used to find the number of bases of  $\mathbf F_q^r$, $q=p^n$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Are parts a) and b) correct?

Comment: Perfectly correct. Another way to prove a) and b) would be to use determinants.

Comment: I got ($p^2$ - $1$)($p^2$ - $p$) = $2,058$, does this sound about right? I'm confused as there are only 49 pairs in $\mathbb Z_7^2$.

Comment: Sorry, |$\mathbb Z_7^2$| = 49.

Comment: You should get $2,016$ bases. The general formula you obtain is correct.

Comment: Of course. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain why there are so many?

Comment: That's just because there are many *pairs* of vectors (linearly independent of not) in $\mathbf F_7^2$. $7^4=2,401$  precisely. Most of them are linearly independent.

Comment: Okay, thanks Bernard. That's good to know.